# Xamarin.Forms Picker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a picker:

```
<Picker Title="Status" x:Name="pickerStatus">
  <Picker.Items>
    <x:String>In Progress</x:String>
    <x:String>Completed</x:String>
    <x:String>Dropped</x:String>
    <x:String>Plan To Take</x:String>
 </Picker.Items>
```

The required value is already stored in a database as a Text value.  How do I display a picker 
on an editable page to load that selected text value from the database into the edit page picker?
I've tried:

```
pickerStatus.SelectedItem = _courseObject.Status;
```

Comment: How about trying to go for the index. `pickerStatus.SelectedIndex=Index`, see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is made for code-behind, if you intend to use ViewModels I can provide a more in-depth answer. But for your case this works:

```
List<string> pickerStates = new List<string> 
{ 
    "In Progress", 
    "Completed", 
    "Dropped", 
    "Plan To Take" 
};
pickerStatus.ItemsSource = pickerStates;
pickerStatus.SelectedIndex = pickerStates
                            .FindIndex(status => status == _courseObject.Status);
```

Comment: Greggz - Thanks for that.  It works perfectly for my needs!

Comment: @BorjeoVonDingle Glad I could help, don't forget to approve it then ;)

Comment: I approved it but I got a message that, because of my low reputation due to a newish account, it is not public.  Sorry!!

Comment: So weird. Well upvote it at least if u can, thanks anyway!!